# Initialize the structure of other structure

Tags: c, initialization

Can i initialize structure if other structure? For example: I have structure:

```
typedef struct _JobParam
{
  MainWin*   mw;
}JobParam;
```

Where MainWin structure too.

In main code i have function:

Can the so-initialize structure or it's wrong way?

```
void load (MainWin* mw)
{
   Param param;
   param.mw = mw;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you already tried doing this and it failed, or are you trying to confirm that it will work before you try it?

Comment: I want to know this is the correct way to initialize the structures of other structure, or not

Comment: You should post your main() so we can see what exactly you are trying to do.  Not enough context to give you the answer you're looking for otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the case you're showing, it's just a pointer that's getting copied so that's fine.  If they were structures, it would also be ok... `gcc` will emit a call to `memcpy` in that case (at least often), but the C standard does allow structure copying:

```
struct s { int x; int y };
struct s a = { 3, 4 };
struct s b = a;
```